# Get-ChildItem is not showing all files in a folder

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

When I call [Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) in PowerShell it is only returning a few of the files that exist in the directory. This is the driver folder, so I tried using the `-Force` parameter in case they were hidden, but with no luck.

It's interesting though because it works perfect on my Windows 7 32 bit, but not 64 bit. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us the exact command you're running and what the output is?

Comment: Just Get-ChildItem.  Output is exactly as a it should be minus a bunch of files that exist in the directory.

Comment: Are you running PS as admin? Might be a security issue.

Comment: Ahh figured it out.  I was running x86 version of Powershell.  Ran the 64bit and it seemed to work.  Not sure how this would change things though...

Comment: If you give the details of what you were trying in your question, then in an answer show details of what you figured out (maybe screen shots) it will improve the question and allow other folks to find a possible solution if they happen to have the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

I believe PowerShell is showing you everything however the folder you're looking at in the x86 PowerShell prompt isn't what you think.  The directory you're actually looking at is under C:\Windows\SysWow64\Drivers and not actually C:\Windows\System32\Drivers.  This is due to a Windows feature (Vista and higher) for 32-bit processes running on 64-bit OS called virtualization (specifically the [File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)).  When you run a 64-bit PowerShell prompt virtualization is not used so you see the real C:\Windows\System32\Drives dir.

From a 32-bit PowerShell prompt, you can see the "real" C:\windows\system32\drivers dir by using this path:

`Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\SysNative\Drivers`

Answer (score 4):

I ran across this while searching for a similar issue. I want to list user folder usage, but run into issues with folder ownership/permissions. Even though I am a local admin, I need to explicitly give myself access. Not ideal. Below gives accurate usage, despite permissions. (Of course, if you want to know more detailed usage, you need to use a for loop or something.)

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object Length -Sum
```

As for what files are included, hidden and system files are not shown by default: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6

- `Hidden` parameter: Hidden files only
- `System` parameter: System files only
- `Force` parameter: Include hidden and system files, with regular files

To confirm, I granted myself permission to one of the user directories. I compared size reported from PowerShell (before granting permission) and that reported in File Explorer (after granting permission). Size and count was the same.

Comment: Seem like alias doesn't like the `-Force` and ended up having to do: `function ls_all {Get-ChildItem -Force}; Set-Alias -Name ll ls_all`.